# I'm getting emails not addressed to me

Tags: email, thunderbird, hotmail, bcc

Now this is driving me nuts. My hotmail account is getting emails that are not addressed to me. I know about the BCC field, but this doesn't appear to be that. Someone with the email address admin@someserver.com sent out an invitation to a lot of people. Now those people are replying back to the invitation. These replies have admin@someserver.com in `To` field (and no other email address in `To` or `CC`), but these replies still end up in my hotmail inbox.

The reason why I think this shouldn't be a BCC thing is that all the replying persons would not be adding my address in the BCC. Even if the admin had my address in the BCC field, that shouldn't appear in the reply.

I checked the mail source and there is no mention of my account anywhere. So what's going on here? I can of course mark that address as junk, but I'm more interested in knowing what's happening.

**EDIT**

Here is the source of one reply email. As you see, it is directed to `sender@aaa.org.pk` and not me. No other hotmail email address appears anywhere in the source.

```
x-store-info:J++/JTCzmObr++wNraA4Pa4f5Xd6uensydyekesGC2M=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=softfail (sender IP is 144.76.69.139) smtp.mailfrom=stylo.naeem@gmail.com; dkim=pass header.d=yahoo.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=nuzhatsalamat@yahoo.com
X-SID-PRA: nuzhatsalamat@yahoo.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTE7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0w
X-Message-Info: BoWLbcrhZCssd1tTeAJGVwQgAiTKs9ggDoTsTZ2cr6OeiRzE9/EslnCEklYGaRIDs7lKsoUqNB331qzklY8IE9BqftmUl5rvHX8RQXMI2UiijKXaD9AwOnHjRqlUNBIR/oDCVedqGTa7VSXBuj6zIb+hUJWVYfJcsdUqKnIqGKk0yDAMUpCWu/e43K0LmMF6xDpG14dVlWGakcifA7Viit3yuCaiwMt9
Received: from OWNEROR-455RINB.home ([144.76.69.139]) by SNT0-MC3-F55.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Wed, 27 Nov 2013 07:55:29 -0800
Received: from nm32-vm1.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com ([72.30.239.137]) by home with MailEnable ESMTP; Wed, 27 Nov 2013 16:45:17 +0100
Received: from [98.139.212.153] by nm32.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 27 Nov 2013 15:45:16 -0000
Received: from [68.142.230.77] by tm10.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 27 Nov 2013 15:45:16 -0000
Received: from [127.0.0.1] by smtp234.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 27 Nov 2013 15:45:16 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=s1024; t=1385567116; bh=3LkNMFXPv5G5CoKart20/InxF83I9d8giBvEuybaSJU=; h=X-Yahoo-Newman-Id:X-Yahoo-Newman-Property:X-YMail-OSG:X-Yahoo-SMTP:X-Rocket-Received:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Importance:From:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=W8+vphm1JXcwqqOa+0Kpbif4d1Q7GZvgz7zBUcluT/zHrQRPsTZ+UK60NDOPMFb8elwk8ABa6p2sUbp8AR/kieIY+emdbYci4OImD5yHtskmOSt9NiT6N/IGA0ASyV3IyJ5uvZWBef+fbksq8UF4uzPr4f5YKWTGInRMzseOLaE=
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 323420.34381.bm@smtp234.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3
X-YMail-OSG: A3ZHf9wVM1mzL9np1_CxBJcQZ2vB_j69b5nCelPAm09hWRR
 dEqCSoYFKg4oJI_btoHjmRM7X4MRUba_Pzn6bu9AzvkvP.EKQEey4N6JGilj
 YUMJE0Vq7EXdXmUA7PHqatw0Aj8vp57VQ7V_51G93aYR2vCzJCz9.9W9Xto.
 h5VFp7eAJ0p5gT7ZvTXKT9rvJPs_619GmfDKq9aPneGZ5AFqWcbQFTPf_FBL
 0MM._ICzqpLFiNPLXL6PsopGnZzPcmEbJBBMT70DsIbGB7rI0P1cndbcj.Nh
 pdxM7SCMmecpkIWIYgHBgCjMMAN71KBWZSJiYN.4wIay84_jCwfSSt1D7Rsl
 pD7DUlyExchqKnS6YkSOv.THGEWm5A923Ra2.iPmJg3Afq4DSV0rZglLK2ZH
 NMlpWgqjC0NwaCVzksfkVVyiYKI82pziLib__HUO_LmlKm6VwgwGYt_qxTIU
 qD_HuE0YCfwDZWQpvMd7VL92laUKinyxO2esCXp2dFywJ_xYOAkm2xKrVg_e
 6uoDUqjfLwSlbpfHh0eIqAnClSQp6gAfUSYQrAOPoxSQd.B9K9f9nwZ6svn.
 GCuE4Yh7YN2Tu97wXYTaLUGKnEykYbYapviE9TXCcY4LyhE.neMgDJa0PScP
 d4Lth4OTbvU7DAP2cMb7EwVDrSqWZF7TKw60oB04c
X-Yahoo-SMTP: nQWD1RSswBDUes8xy08bkPEmqLy9o8hUrvo-
X-Rocket-Received: from [192.168.1.7] (nuzhatsalamat@39.47.114.193 with )
        by smtp234.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with SMTP; 27 Nov 2013 15:45:16 +0000 UTC
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 20:44:13 +0500
Subject: Re: Emotional Intelligence Workshop by Brig (R) Mowadat Hussain
 Rana in AFIC Rawalpindi
Message-ID: <rnqkfwakbpmmak7kmcpyok5i.1385567053379@email.android.com>
Importance: normal
From: nuzhatsalamat <nuzhatsalamat@yahoo.com>
To: sender@aaa.org.pk
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--_com.android.email_3151463546021830"
Precedence: list
Reply-To: sender@aaa.org.pk
Sender: stylo.naeem@gmail.com
Return-Path: stylo.naeem@gmail.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 27 Nov 2013 15:55:29.0144 (UTC) FILETIME=[1852A780:01CEEB89]

----_com.android.email_3151463546021830
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

LOT OF BASE64 DATA HERE

----_com.android.email_3151463546021830
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

LOT OF BASE64 DATA HERE

----_com.android.email_3151463546021830--
```

Comment: Its probably impossible to answer this question on the information you have provided.  We would need to get a copy of the email headers to even have a look-in, and even then, we don't know all your accounts and who you are, so its a long shot.

Comment: I think you're getting those emails because they're addressed to you, while in headers there are different "TO:" and "X-Rcpt-To:" and so on.. please, provide full headers of emails [you can get them by downloading the messages with outlook] ;)

Comment: This doesn't look like a reply to an invitation. It looks like **spam**. Spammers can connect to a mail-server and push mail into it with your e-mail as the destination address. This doesn't necessarily mean your address needs to be in the To-header. (That works with the same concept as the BCC where your address is also not in the headers). Also the fact the To-address **is the same** as the reply-to (sender@aaa.org.pk). That is not normal. Spammers use this method to circumvent spam-filters (and apparently that worked in this case ;(